Why are the two LEDS getting short circuited here?
After simulating the circuit on Tinkercad, the last two diodes got bypassed. I also don't understand why P1- in the diagram is not placed after D22 just like in the breadboard, bypassing all of D23, D24, D25 and D26 if we are to bypass. I attempt to make it like the last diagram. LEDs are used to easily understand current flow, not for any design purpose.




Where is it from? What is the purpose?

I was just practicing parallel circuits and this left me confused.

LEDs are not like regular light bulbs... neither resistors as in your second diagram. You can't just connect them directly in parallel to a voltage source. They require a current-limiting resistor to prevent damage.

I have edited and added the targeted diagram although it is not about my diagram. I just want to know why it got short circuited.

I just used LEDs to see whether circuit is flowing as it is inconvenient to check with DMMs online

Then connect resistors in series (one resistor for two LEDs in series is enough).

LEDs are not resistors and so this whole exercise seems pretty senseless. You will fry some LEDs and that's about all you'll learn from this.

I don't intend to use it in real life ....

It has no purpose in theory either.

Use resistors if you want to learn about how parallel and series connections of resistors work. LEDs are useless for that purpose, since they are highly nonlinear and don't behave like resistors at all. The "short circuit" or bypass happens because diodes have exponential voltage-vs-current dependency. The single diode will carry most of the current since the voltage across it is much higher than the voltage across each of the series-connected diodes. Those diodes aren't completely bypassed. They still conduct. Not enough to see easily without a current meter.

That looks messy and difficult to see what is happening in both on TinkerCad and in the schematics.
However, there looks like to be a series chain of two LEDs being bypassed in parallel with with one single LED.
As the one LED limits the voltage to (say) 1.6V, then it is not enough to light up two LEDs that will require 3.2V to light up.

As already noted, the schematic is difficult to follow, and the breadboard render is worse.
I've put the following circuit together using the Falstad Circuit Simulator (click to open) - as you can see, the curent distribution between the LEDs is incredibly unbalanced. Your 10v supply is also not current limited, and this shows D21 dealing with a full 58A(!!), While D25 and D26 get only 33μA!


Looking at the circuit diagram, you have chains of 2, 3 or 4 LEDs across the positive and negative supply.
LEDs are not resistors, so they don't share current like resistors.
To a rough approximation, an LED has a specific turn on voltage. It's about 1.6V for a red one. Below that voltage, it barely conducts. Above it, the current gets so great that the LED burns out.
In your circuit, the 2 LEDs will turn on at about 3.2V. they will then steal all the current. The voltage will never get high enough for the longer strings to turn on.

The drawing makes no sense to me, but the schematic (posted at this time) is clear.
D24 is across D25 and D26 in series, so it effectively "shorts out" those two LEDs.
But . . .
D22 shorts out D23, D24, D25, and D26.  Thus, only D21 and D22 are lit.
